# How to customize emails generated by adding a task in sharepoint designer

Tags: workflow, infopath, sharepoint-designer

the email that is generated when a task is assigned by sharepoint workflow doesn't fit my needs and I would either like to customize it.  If anyone knows how to customize this email, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do is to disable the default email alert on the task list by going to list settings. Then create another workflow on the task list that gets triggered on item creation and only when the item creator is the first workflow. Then use a send mail activity from designer and you can customize that to your heart's content.

Answer (score 0):

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/video-create-an-approval-workflow-in-sharepoint-designer-2010-VA101897477.aspx (or http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wfGDBzQvAwI)

Starting at 5:37, this video show how to customize the email sent by a workflow task using SharePoint Designer 2010.

Comment: FYI, the below video is not for customizing a TASK, it is for customizing an approval workflow which are not the same unfortunatly for those looking for customization to task emails.